# How to make the jQuery $()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that you that in jQuery you can do $("element"), but I want to know how to make it in pure js. Here is my code:

```
var element;
if(selector.charAt(0) == "#"){
    element = document.getElementById(selector);
}else if(selector.charAt(0) == "."){
    if(!document.getElementsByClassName){
        element = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }else{
        element = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    }
}else{
    element = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
return element;
```

And then I do this:

```
function X(selector){return new X.selector(selector);}
```

Unfortunately, it only gets one element can someone give me a solution.

Comment: Can you provide a working example where you only get one element?

Comment: Have to remove the prefixes `#` and `.` when using `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()`. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also some methods return a collection vs single element

Comment: `$ = document.querySelectorAll;` Done.

Comment: Can you show me an example in JSFiddle?

Comment: Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/zwfjt9j2/